# Is it possible to use unicode character within glob pattern in mime definition file?

Tags: wildcards, mime-types, freedesktop, xdg

I'm issuing the command `xdg-mime install nv-custom.xml` - using this file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="text/x-customtest">
        <comment></comment>
        <glob weight="60" pattern="*...someUnicodeHere"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Is it possible to use unicode in the glob's pattern field?

I tried Ctrl + Shift + U followed by a code, which works fine, but then the file does not have any effect, whereas it works just fine with "regular" text.